# The origins of fork()

Tags: operating-system

Is `fork()` older than C? What are its origins? I might think that `fork()` was created along with C (1970s) but I recently read a reference to a 1963 paper where `fork()` was mentioned.

Comment: When learning about `fork()`, it's also worth exploring BSD's `vfork()`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `fork()` system call is definitely older than the C language because it already existed in the [UNIX v0](http://doc.cat-v.org/unix/v0/UnixEditionZero.pdf) draft, page 18 of the PDF, when the C language hasn't been conceived yet.

The mechanism was different from what we're used to:

> Except while UNIX is bootstrapping itself into operation, a new
>   process can come into existence in only one way: by use of the
>   `fork` system call.
>
> ```
> processid = fork(label)
> ```
>
> When fork is executed by a process, it splits into two independently
>   executing processes. The two processes have core images
>   which are copies of each other, but they are not precisely
>   equivalent: one of them is considered the parent process. In the
>   parent, control does not return directly from the `fork`, but instead passes to location `label`; in the child process, there is a
>   normal return. The `processid` returned by the `fork` call is the identification of the other, offspring process.

Comment: That looks like an editorial mistake, mixing parent and child – the parent would need the child's processid, not the child, right?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann You're most likely right, as the last sentence indicates that the most recent phrase should be about the parent process.

Comment: I don't have any documentation on Multics but could this have been taken from Multics - after all both the Unix (formerly Unics)  inventors were previously Multics programmers.

Comment: @cup In a conversation the other day I was told that the concept of forking a process did exist in Multics, but the evolution of the calling convention is of interest as well.

Answer (score 23):

An article on the history of fork appeared in the [IEEE Annals of the History of Computing 2016 vol. 38](https://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/an/2016/03/man2016030084.html).

This article states that fork was invented by Melvin Conway in 1962 when considering the allocation of tasks to processors in multi-processor systems.

Comment: The original Conway paper can be found on page 164 of http://www.textfiles.com/bitsavers/pdf/afips/1963-11_%2324.pdf

Comment: @dmw Unfortunately, your link gives a 404; any chance you can find an active one? Please?

Comment: @RichardT Here you go https://www.docdroid.net/oEodAHw/1963-11-24-pdf#page=146

Comment: @dmw I'm VERY appreciative for you providing that link. As it was published less than two weeks before my birth AND as I have spent over 44 years in computing (and am still very active), this is a VERY interesting read! I've downloaded the whole thing and while I really don't have time to read ALL of it, I'd never have found it without your link! THANKS!

Comment: @RichardT the lesson is clear.. never delete a PDF you've downloaded once ;) Best wishes, and glad you liked it